# Keypress not firing In Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I am using a JavaScript `keypress` switch to fire events, and it works fine in webkit browsers, but it does not work in Firefox. Can anyone help? The code I am using is:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
switch(e.keyCode) { 

    case 39:
    event.preventDefault();
            alert("Arrow Key");
 }
break;

    case 37:
           event.preventDefault();
            alert("Arrow Key");
}
});
```

The functions I am trying to fire are more complex than just an alert, but i thought i would keep it simple for the explanation.

Comment: I have tried keydown, and keyup and all produce the same results in firefox (does not work) and all of them work in webkit browsers.

Comment: Are you explicitly passing the event from Html down to the function?

Comment: @you should use keydown on some textbox or so right , why are you doing in document , is it global

Comment: yeah, basically just trying to create some shortcuts triggered by keypresses. This isnt the exact code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an syntax-error(a wrong bracket `}` before `break;`), and an undefined object(event) inside your function.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
switch(e.keyCode) { 

case 39:
e.preventDefault();
        alert("Arrow Key");

break;

case 37:
       e.preventDefault();
        alert("Arrow Key");
}
});
```

The wrong object(**event**) does'nt occur in MSIE, as there is always a global object called "event"

Comment: ah, so simple. Thanks so much. Worked like a charm. Dunno why i was writing event.PreventDefault();

Comment: Maybe because inside the jquery-docs they always use  `event.preventDefault()` . But they also call the functions-argument "event".

Comment: @dr molle brilliant , nice catch , i was looking at it but couldn't identify. I did lot of stuff using..keydowns

Answer (score 3):

IIRC Firefox use charCode and not keyCode.

Can you try that :

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
kCode = (e.keyCode)? e.keyCode: e.charCode;
switch(kCode) { 

case 39:
event.preventDefault();
        alert("Arrow Key");
}
break;

case 37:
       event.preventDefault();
        alert("Arrow Key");
}
});
```